# ShowDialog from another thread and get result

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms

I want to display a dialog from a secondary thread (not GUI).
Main form has a method for showing the second form

```
    public string ShowDialogSafe()
    {
        if(this.InvokeRequired)
            return (string)Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => ShowDialogSafe()));
        else
        {
            var frm = new Form2();
            if(frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                return frm.MyResult;
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Is safe to call this from a secondary thread?

```
string s = this.ShowDialogSafe();
```

Will the secondary thread be blocked till the user closes Form2?

EDIT
Why it's unsafe?
Doesn't Invoke() guaranties that Form2 and it's controls are created on the GUI thread?

Comment: It will probably work but it is a very bad design. A worker thread should not need a Dialog.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's a worker thread that needs a user intervention.

Comment: Then it is badly designed.

Comment: No, you'll have to insert "un" before the "safe" part of that name.  Winforms supports showing dialogs on a worker thread just fine, problem is that most of its control classes don't.  The ones that subscribe the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event and hope that this event gets fired on the right thread.  Not otherwise really different from the completely frazzled user that has no idea where the dialog came from or why it is behind another window or when he never saw it while clicking away and accidentally hitting the Close button.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant So InvokeRequired (anti)pattern does not solve the "safe" problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code should work. Invoke is a blocking operation, so you non-gui-thread is waiting until the invoked method has finished.
But usually, you would only put your non-gui code into a background thread and would show the UI elements within the gui thread (e.g. in a progress event of an BackgroundWorker or when the task has finished...)